# Passing an array from c # to c++ like parameter

Tags: c#, c++, opencv

I am using native code in C #. I'm trying to pass an array from C# to C++ using Pinvoke. Once in C++, I want to fill that array that I passed as parameter with the values ​​of a cv::Mat. The problem is that I am using the copy function and I do not think that this is happening well the parameters. Can anybody help me? Greetings and thank you.

C++ code:

```
__declspec(dllexport)
void ProcessFrame(unsigned char* arr) {
VideoCapture camera;
if (!camera.open(0))
{
    return;
}

Mat frame;
camera >> frame;
if (frame.empty()) {
    return;
}
int tam = frame.cols * frame.rows;
copy(frame.begin, frame.end, arr);
}
```

C# code:

```
[DllImport("NativoPrincipio.dll")]
public static extern void ProcessFrame(out byte[] img);

        byte[] imgData = new byte[webcamTexture.width * webcamTexture.height];
        ProcessFrame(out imgData);

        Debug.Log(imgData.Length);
        Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(webcamTexture.width, webcamTexture.height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
        tex.LoadRawTextureData(imgData);
        tex.Apply();
        GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = tex;
```

Comment: You can't use `new byte`. You'll have to invoke the Marshaller and have the signature be `IntPtr`.

Comment: `public static extedn void ProcessFrame(IntPtr img);` And then to call it `GCHandle hArray= GCHandle.Alloc(byteArray, GCHandleType.Pinned);
IntPtr ptrArray= hArray.AddrOfPinnedObject(); ProcessFrame(ptrArray); hArray.Free();` And do not forget to add `Extern "C"` on your C++ call to prevent name mangling.

Comment: With this code, there are times when it does. In other unity falls. The problem comes in in the c ++ COPY function. And my partner tells me not to use memcpy